# Do we need to add again "complementiser-that" before "the second clause"

Tags: complements

> The two advantages of self-service are that there is no waiting to be served and **that** there is a wide variety of choice.

Do we need to add again  "complementiser-that" before
"the second clause".

Answer (score 1):

No, you can omit it.

> The two advantages of self-service are that there is no waiting to be served and there is a wide variety of choice.

Note that the pattern *X are that there is Y and there is Z* doesn't really add more information to this sentence (you are simply repeating forms of *to be* needlessly), just more words.  A more compact and clear way of expressing this is:

> The two advantages of self-service are no waiting to be served and a wide variety of choice.